# What's $(1 2 3)(1 4 5)$? Everybody gives a different answer.

Tags: permutation-cycles

From my calculation: $(1 4 5 2 3)$.

From Joseph Gallian's *Contemporary Modern Algebra*, 9th edition, page 100:

[image: pe]

From WolframAlpha:

[image]

Comment: Note WolframAlpha interprets the product left-to-right, not right-to-left as you have done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, the book isn't mistaken but might be slightly misleading.
The order of the permutation $(1 2 3)(1 4 5)$ is equal to the order of the permutation $(1 4 5 3 2)$, but the disjoint cycle form of $(1 2 3)(1 4 5)$ is $(1 4 5 2 3)$.
Also, note that Wolframalpha permutations goes from left to right, try inputting $(1 4 5)(1 2 3)$.